# What's problem with my script that my clustering seems incorrect with pheatmap?

Tags: r, pheatmap

I want to plot my data with pheatmap and I don't know what's the problem with my script that cluster1 is closer to cluster2 than cluster3. It seems that cluster2 is more different from cluster1 and 3 and should place farther. Of note, I don't want to scale my data.

[image]

Here is my script

```
pheatmap(data, show_colnames = T, show_rownames = T,fontsize=12,angle_col = 45,
         color=colorRampPalette(c('navy', "white", "#EA0764"))(100))
```

And here is my data

```
> dput(data)
    structure(list(BRCA = c(0.230749533, 0.070357349, -0.239713974, 
    0.703365372, 0.327406476, 0.788362186, -0.145366946, 0.193414478, 
    -0.427479686, -0.548639578, -0.227693913, 0.007319619, -0.282273491, 
    -0.127434584, -0.465189842, 0.075561033), COAD = c(0.332890058, 
    0.09527495, -0.178301154, 0.924092152, 0.612677767, 1.221923426, 
    -0.276093973, 0.958147584, 0.379735117, 0.029502217, -0.054424396, 
    0.300349746, 0.650179747, 0.155807135, 0.028132132, 0.378762531
    ), LUAD = c(0.829893225, 0.2606768, -0.1821214, 0.692721414, 
    0.688720644, 1.017873137, 0.056591306, 0.289392746, 0.005723013, 
    -0.388952621, 0.256912977, 0.186641748, 0.017661571, -0.270885042, 
    -0.16046479, -0.097848349), LUSC = c(1.159170792, 0.533298568, 
    0.01576386, 0.901518727, 1.14831359, 1.40438067, 0.150671917, 
    0.627636011, -0.221484602, -0.621483798, 0.104588174, 0.377637951, 
    0.427781729, -0.444719169, -0.26419915, 0.042390119), STAD = c(0.494758767, 
    0.125857219, -0.016071377, 0.203326756, 0.784281834, 1.178387864, 
    0.159516768, 0.711241935, -0.03263392, -0.30666277, -0.056459557, 
    -0.202547246, 0.182941332, -0.139104068, -0.10655886, 0.262286026
    ), THCA = c(-0.179233856, -0.035498075, -0.634293378, -0.018114387, 
    -0.029922798, 0.21657491, 0.040044405, -0.085685179, -0.33303136, 
    0.206747289, -0.112778263, 0.115131275, -0.217347418, -0.178894761, 
    -0.36714963, -0.186071557), UCEC = c(0.228783922, 0.087425611, 
    -0.126598752, 0.985393743, 0.203059279, 0.962485138, -0.050525831, 
    0.097276188, -0.386458244, -0.47970207, -0.542838744, 0.090891178, 
    0.146372654, -0.148096616, -0.404956997, -0.099997733), ESCA = c(0.515480135, 
    -0.128144806, -0.001233162, 0.375547256, 0.868288817, 0.846731963, 
    -0.09909923, 0.215571998, -0.327098337, -0.686121329, -0.332182132, 
    0.081704439, 0.022641456, -0.021981116, -0.51026229, 0.33227835
    ), KIRC = c(-0.059448938, 0.061253477, -0.605107439, 0.135114673, 
    0.286596096, -0.085087897, 0.125670677, 0.394701809, 0.199182749, 
    0.400641612, 0.410932558, -0.159331938, 0.072832951, 0.281035001, 
    0.391288988, 0.066404822), PRAD = c(0.128646849, 0.009521855, 
    0.126533666, 0.542727651, 0.000694083, 0.32625358, -0.131356051, 
    0.087581413, -0.264907468, -0.201647563, -0.088937601, -0.110720233, 
    0.343355006, 0.205884841, 0.235804542, -0.049704744), LIHC = c(0.581419719, 
    0.121962843, -0.661213563, 0.219828076, 0.430757101, 0.935526611, 
    0.090115912, 1.00110355, -0.368156896, -0.264853361, -0.249296333, 
    -0.216131716, -0.161492687, -0.096794496, 0.091178754, 0.353416867
    ), GBM = c(-0.327762529, -0.100512851, -1.170250005, 0.973784849, 
    0.22308926, 0.605125243, -0.170939552, -0.213415522, -0.548838235, 
    -0.236635581, -0.302241958, 0.09930227, 0.628040053, 0.11204205, 
    -0.275029974, 0.540026962), BLCA = c(0.447543962, 0.296830523, 
    -0.242805848, 1.077955557, 0.433840673, 0.78600795, -0.150633173, 
    -0.11054011, -0.552050335, -0.27309979, 0.05763108, -0.30845115, 
    0.073324125, -0.396794707, -0.380437894, 0.130825992)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Gene1", 
    "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5", "Gene6", "Gene7", "Gene8", 
    "Gene9", "Gene10", "Gene11", "Gene12", "Gene13", "Gene14", "Gene15", 
    "Gene16"))
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please, could you give more details about your problem? How do you expect that Cluster 1, 2 and 3 should be? In your figure, Cluster 2 and 3 are closer that Cluster 1 and 2. Why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: Dear @MarcoSandri, Thanks for your reply. Since most of the values in cluster2 are zero or less, I think it should place farther than cluster1. Indeed, in my opinion, cluster3 should place between cluster1 and 2 because it has more positive values like cluster1.

Comment: In the horizontal dendrogram of the figure, the length of the horizontal lines indicates the degree of difference between branches. The longer the line, the greater the difference. The vertical orientation of the dendrogram is irrelevant. Cluster1 and 2 are vertically close but their real distance is greater than the distance between Cluster 2 and 3. See the following link about how to read a dendrogram: https://www.displayr.com/what-is-dendrogram/